# When does the show method perform?

Tags: php, laravel, function, methods, controller

I have a controller named `PostController` and a model named `Post`.
This is my PostController:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('posts.index')->with('posts',$posts);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {

    }
```

and this is my post.index :

```
@if (count($posts) > 1)
    @foreach ($posts as $item)

        <div class="card-header mb-3">
            <h3><a href="/posts/{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->title }}</a></h3>
            <small>Created At {{ $item->created_at }}</small>
        </div>


    @endforeach


@else
    <p>No Post Found</p>
@endif
```

Look at the below image :

[image]

Why does laravel run the show method when I click on post 1 (like in the image)?
Does it mean every time we click on a link, the show method will work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does laravel run the show method when I click on post 1 (like in the image)?

Because the url pattern in your href of the link matches the pattern for the `show` route.

> Does it mean every time we click on a link, the show method will work ?

No. The `show` route is only used when your link matches the `show` pattern in your `routes/web.php` file. To use a different route, use a different url. For example, if you change your url from this:

```
<a href="/posts/{{ $item->id }}">
```

to this:

```
<a href="/posts/{{ $item->id }}/edit">
```

Then the `edit` route would be followed instead.

#### Why:

This is the code for the link you are talking about:

```
<h3><a href="/posts/{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->title }}</a></h3>
```

The formation `/posts/$id` is the default formation for the `show` route in `routes/web.php`.

In your `routes/web.php` file you have either:

```
Route::get('/posts/{$id}', 'PostsController@show');
```

or:

```
Route::resource('/posts', 'PostsController');
```

`Route::resource` (when used with 'posts' in this example) is short-hand for:

```
Route::get('/posts', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');
Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostsController@show');
Route::get('/posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsController@edit');
Route::patch('/posts/{id}', 'PostsController@update');
Route::delete('/posts/{id}', 'PostsController@delete');
```

As you can see, the `show` route is included in `Route::resource`, and matches the url pattern that you have given in `posts.index`.

Comment: completely solved ! Thanks So Much For Your Simple & Perfect Answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a route file which connects the show method and the PostController controller. The route triggers the controller with the corresponding methods. When you click on post 1, you will get a URL path posts/id, this path means the following route and the route triggers the method and the controller

Route file find in `routes/web.php` file

```
Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostController@show');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you created a resource route in your `routes/web.php` like so:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
```

When you perform a `GET` request and supply the `id` as the second url segment, this is routed to the `PostsController@show` method.

You can learn more about resource routes/controllers [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers).